# RN Webview not loading images from project level folder

Tags: react-native, webview, imagesource

I have a webview that loads a local html, with some js scripts inside. Everything in this is working fine, except the images located outside android or ios folder.

When the html file was out of android and ios folder, it resolved images, but it was not where .html  have to be.

**WebView:**

```
<WebView
    source={{uri: isAndroid?
    'file:///android_asset/webviews/map.html'
    :'./external/widget/map.html'}}
    ref={( webView ) => this.webView = webView}
    onMessage={() => this.onWebViewMessage()}
    onNavigationStateChange={() => this.trackMap(this.state.dados)} />
```

**Inside script tag within html file (android case)**

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: posicao,
            icon: '../../../../../external/images/' + icon.toString() + '_' + direction + '.png'),
            map: mapa
          });
```

**Also tried:**

'myapp/external/images/...'

'file:///external/images/...'

**Project structure:**

```
myapp
|
|
|_android
|  |_ app
|     |_ src
|        |_ main
|           |_ assets
|              |_ webviews
|                 |_ map.html
|  
|_ external
|  |_ images
|     |_ 1_north.png
|     |_ 2_east.png 
|     |_ <icon>_<direction>.png
|      ...
```

How can I get these images paths? Do I really have to put images inside res android folder and the relative ios folder as well?

Comment: By now, the work around was to put the external images in assets from android folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `icon: '../../../../../../../external/images/ + ...'`

Even if this is working you really should use react native map instead of a webview. This is a really bad practice in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. Well, I do not believe its a matter of '../' count. I also tried to put images in android directory, but it still not working. Indeed, it's a bad practice to use webview instead of rn-maps, but my customers require his own map